# If Russia plans to demilitarize Ukraine, does that mean (e.g.) they plan to take over or dismantle the Kharkiv tank factory (and design bureau)?

Tags: russian-federation, military, ukraine, media

Ukraine has inherited (from Soviet times) the [Morozov design bureau](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kharkiv_Morozov_Machine_Building_Design_Bureau) and the [Malyshev (tank) factory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malyshev_Factory), both located in Kharkiv. These have been responsible for a non-trivial amount of armored vehicles, even in post-Soviet times, e.g. some 300 T-80UD have been [exported to Pakistan](https://thediplomat.com/2017/03/ukraine-and-pakistan-move-forward-with-armor-deal/) from Ukraine.

I know that the Kremlin has been pretty vague in official communiques what they mean in practice by "denazification and demilitarization" of Ukraine, but often enough Kremlin insiders have intimated on Russian TV one thing or the other about their personal vision on various things. So, I'm curious if Ukraine's arms production facilities have factored into any such discussion on Russian state or state-proxy media (which in Russia nowadays means most TV and newspapers). Have there been concrete proposals aired in Russian media, from politically influent sources, what to do with Ukraine's arms production facitlies?

(N.B. [according](http://america.aljazeera.com/multimedia/2015/2/kharkiv-tank-factory.html) to Al-Jazeera, Russians are the majority in Kharkiv, and there was even an insurrection attempt in the city in 2014. So, I guess just annexing the city is a distinct possibility for Russia.)

Comment: Given that the Kremlin has been pretty vague on this, this is probably impossible to answer (for now at least).

Answer (score 1):

There are different possibilities here:

- [According to Putin, Ukraine might cease to exist as a state](https://www.euronews.com/2022/03/05/ukraine-s-statehood-is-in-jeopardy-warns-vladimir-putin). In this case the problem doe snot even pose itself (though it is an unlikely solution, as the partisan fight might make holding Ukraine impossible in a long term).
- One could dismantle the tank factory and other similar objects, as suggested in the OP.
- One could set verification measures to ensure that there is no production, or that it is kept below the specified level, or that all the produce is exported to Russia or the exporters designated by Russia. The precedents of such controls on a large scale are those imposed to check compliance with nuclear treaties (in case of USA and Russia vis-à-vis each other, or in respect to states as, e.g., Iran). A more ancient example is the limitations on the size of the German army and its equipment imposed by the Versaille treaty (this famously failed - but that was arguably due to the guarantors of the treaty being reluctant to enforce the compliance.)

Comment: There might be more than one Ukraine (plus parts lost to some states). Internets are aplenty with blueprints of partition of Ukraine. In this case, newfound buffer states are tasked with figuring out the partisan problem, and also work against each other to prevent reunification.